# ReactJS reconciliation when a parent DOM node changes type

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A component renders the following React element tree.

```
<div>
  <Counter />
</div>
```

A state or props change then occurs and render is triggered, resulting in the following React element tree.

```
<span>
  <Counter />
</span>
```

Will the instance of the `Counter` component be completely re-instantiated, constructor and all?

If so, does this same behaviour apply to non-root nodes e.g.:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <Counter />
  </div>
</div>
```

transitioning to...

```
<div>
  <span>
    <Counter />
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will re-instantiated `Couter` component on

```
<div>
  <Counter />
</div>
```

to

```
<span>
  <Counter />
</span>
```

The process specified in [Reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html) says:

> This will destroy the old Counter and remount a new one.

For second example it will compare `<div>` first, there is no change but the next is same scenario as above so it will also `remount` the `Counter` component.

Comment: Thank you. So it is a completely new instance of the `Counter` component.

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#elements-of-different-types):

> Whenever the root elements have different types, React will tear down
>   the old tree and **build the new tree from scratch**. Going from `<a>` to
>   `<img>`, or from `<Article>` to `<Comment>`, or from `<Button>` to `<div>` - `any`
>   of those will lead to a full rebuild.

So yes, in both cases everything below the node with a new type will be fully reconstructed.

**Working demo**:

```js
class Inner extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log('Inner constructor called.')
    }

    render() {
        return <p>{`<${this.props.tag}>`}</p>;
    }
}

const Container = ({Tag}) => (
    <Tag>
        <Inner tag={Tag} />
    </Tag>
);

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tag: 'div',
        };
    }

    changeTag = () => this.setState(state => state.tag === 'div' ? {tag: 'span'} : {tag: 'div'});

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.changeTag}>Change tag</button>
                <Container Tag={this.state.tag} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"><!--Filled by React--></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```